# Question About the Physiology of Seizures

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, neuroanatomy, neurology

Absence seizures usually occur in children between ages 4 to 14 [(Hopkins Hospital)](http://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/healthlibrary/conditions/nervous_system_disorders/absence_seizures_134,16). Spontaneous remission occurs in 65–70% of patients during adolescence [(Medicine Central)](https://im.unboundmedicine.com/medicine/view/5-Minute-Clinical-Consult/116854/all/Seizure_Disorder__Absence).

My question is what takes place biologically that allows you to 'grow out of them?' Is it synapse pruning in the brain or something? I have looked everywhere online but can't seem to understand the physiology of how one grows out of seizures.

Comment: @anongoodnurse - absolutely not - but, migrating a question should be done on the basis of being explicitly offtopic. In this case I am not doubting the expertise on Health; rather I am questioning this being offtopic here.